# Codeigniter limit on Access database

Tags: sql, codeigniter, ms-access, activerecord

I have the following "Active Record" setup:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Orders');
$this->db->join('MPC_Agents', 'Orders.UserName = MPC_Agents.UserName', 'inner');    
$this->db->limit(50,20);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Using `$this->db->last_query();` mereley outputs:

```
SELECT * FROM (Orders) INNER JOIN MPC_Agents ON Orders.UserName = MPC_Agents.UserName
```

Why won't it apply the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit is not available in MS Access SQL. You can select Top:

```
SELECT Top 10 Id FROM Table Order BY Id
```

Or

```
SELECT Top 10 Id FROM Table 
WHERE ID Not IN (SELECT Top 10 ID From Table ORDER BY Id)
Order BY Id
```

Comment: Completed with the syntax: `$this->db->select("TOP $limit *");`

Comment: hi @rickyduck
can you provide the complete code for your solution... thank you..
:D

Answer (score 0):

Put your limit fun top of the query and edit as

```
 $this->db->limit(20,50);
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('Orders');
 $this->db->join('MPC_Agents', 'Orders.UserName = MPC_Agents.UserName', 'inner');
 $this->db->get();
```

Hope it better works